# plant ID requested

Tags: identification, leaves

I often see this plant with huge spinose-dentate leaves growing in shady spots around town. What is it?

[image: my photograph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acanthus mollis Bear's  Breeches...super shade evergreen zones 5 and up.

Comment: Bear's breeches... and semi evergreen perennial

Comment: Zone 5 they were evergreen year round.  Loved the shade.

Comment: Hmm, weird - they only remain evergreen here in a very mild winter, and our winters are  nothing like as cold  as those in Zone 5... listed as semi evergreen for the UK (zone 7/8)

Comment: stormy, do you have a link for that? The things I find online are mostly listed, as @Bamboo said, zones 7 and up. Some of the other cultivars, like A. hungaricus and A. spinosus both start at zone 5, but seem to have more pointed leaves. I might not be looking in the right place though.

Comment: @Sue So far as I know, A. mollis is zone 7 up only. A. hungaricus is hardy zone 5 up, but it doesn't look quite the same - A. spinosus does, indeed, have narrower, more spiky leaves.

Comment: Shoot, I planted so many of these in the Seattle or Pacific NW coastal environment it is like I slept with these guys.  I shall look up one of my main nurseries in Woodinville, Bellevue, Seattle area where I purchased tons of them.  Zone 5 IS Seattle with the maritime influence no problemo.  I had to satisfy the very very rich with plants that DID NOT DISAPPEAR and  leave a muddy spot.  Same dang plant...there are also some other plants listed as 7 that I planted down to zone 4, with no problems...Colts foot...starts with a p...peta something or other...I'll get back to you.

Comment: Wasn't able to talk with one of my main wholesale nurseries...the people I knew just might be dead, grins though not  funny.  And this wasn't that dependent on the microclimate although shady areas are usually a protected climate anyway.

Comment: @stormy - Seattle is listed as USDA zone 8b, not 5 - I knew it was zone 8 at least because that's the same as most of the UK

Comment: @Stormy you thinking of *Petasites*? I have an *Acanthus mollis* which doesn't quite disappear in my garden overwinter (Cotswolds, UK). It's not happy - bit too sunny for it at the moment and it has never flowered. I would move it but I don't really have anywhere suitable.

Comment: @what is your zone, George?  Maybe the maritime influence in Seattle/Bellevue makes a huge difference yet it has always been zone 5.  Petasites YES, I got a root from one of my beloved projects...10+ years working with a wonderful woman, rich but beautiful and real.  Also, I think the project ended up in the $300K range, easily.  Lucky for me the golf course they were on used Poa annua and they couldn't keep a decent lawn so I got to take out all the lawn and make a wonderful garden, front and back AND maintain it as well.  Petasites is an amazing plant; the leaves were easily 1 1/2 feet plus!